# Animate first child of ListView on xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

Hello fellow developers,

I have a ListView with, you gess it, ViewCells.
As part of the first tutorial on how to work with the app, I need to animate some of the elements of the first viewcell, so the user can understand that clicking in that element will do some stuff.

I tried with MVVM:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="{Binding CellName}" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="20">
```

and then

```
AccessPage[0].CellName = "TutorialCell";
```

but

```
FindByName<ViewCell>("TutorialCell")
```

returns null.

I can only access the item that is binded to the StackLayout, but not the StackLayout itself, so I can:

```
element.ScaleTo(1.05, 200);
```

Am I thinking this wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: I think I would inherit from ViewCell and create a custom view cell and put your animation code in there, you can create your own BindableProperty in this custom view cell to indicate whether it's the tutorial cell, or just listen for PropertyChanged events. Another option would be to use a data template selector.

Comment: Thank you @Bill, I am working on that aproach, but how can I access the "tutorialCell" to start the animation? I have a message explaining what the "blinking" element does, so when the message appears, the element should "blink"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you? Create a new class that inherits from ListView and override the SetupContent method:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public Cell FirstRow { get; set; }
    protected override void SetupContent(Cell content, int index)
    {
        if (index == 0) FirstRow = content;
        base.SetupContent(content, index);
    }
}
```

Then you could access the FirstRow property of your custom ListView.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for CollectionView?

Answer (score 2):

You can also cast:

```
ITemplatedItemsView<Cell> templatedItemsView = listView as ITemplatedItemsView<Cell>;
ViewCell firstCell = templatedItemsView.TemplatedItems[0] as ViewCell;
```